# Alphabetically sorting over multiple column-height rows

Tags: excel, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, I have a spreadsheet that looks something like this

[image]

I need to be able to alphabetically order only on the `Name` column while maintaining structure and order of the other columns. E.g. after ordering from A > Z, I would expect to see Mr Black first, and the 3 corresponding rows that detail him, i.e. A14-A16, with B14-O16 not having changed

Could someone give me an idea if this is possible or not, and if so, how this can be achieved.  Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to create a "connecting" column - that'll contain the value from column A and an index - and sort by it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess here would be to give the bellow cells the value of the cells you want to sort up to the height of their data.

Like below :

[image: Not sorted]

Then when you sort, you get this result :

[image: sorted]

When you're done, delete redundant values for the first columns manually or with a VBA macro